# "atomic_t" in Linux

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system

I'm studying Linux kernel with Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love.

As you know, this book uses an old version of Linux. It's in 2.6 version.

`atomic_t` has `volatile int counter`. But newly Linux version's `atomic_t` has `int counter` not `volatile`.

Why was `volatile` removed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because volatile variables are not atomic variables. The only point in using `volatile` is to prevent possible compiler optimisations, which is not the same as preventing unwanted concurrent access.

In that regard, the use of `volatile` is almost never correct.

You can read more about it in [Semantics and Behavior of Atomic and Bitmask Operations](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/atomic_ops.html).

Quoting a small part of it:

> *** WARNING: atomic_read() and atomic_set() DO NOT IMPLY BARRIERS! ***
>
> Some architectures may choose to use the volatile keyword, barriers, or inline
>   assembly to guarantee some degree of immediacy for atomic_read() and
>   atomic_set().  This is not uniformly guaranteed, and may change in the future,
>   so all users of atomic_t should treat atomic_read() and atomic_set() as simple
>   C statements that may be reordered or optimized away entirely by the compiler
>   or processor, and explicitly invoke the appropriate compiler and/or memory
>   barrier for each use case.  Failure to do so will result in code that may
>   suddenly break when used with different architectures or compiler
>   optimizations, or even changes in unrelated code which changes how the
>   compiler optimizes the section accessing atomic_t variables.
>
> *** YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED! ***

Comment: Thank you. But then, I want to know why kernel use struct for int variable. I mean why not just use "atomic_t counter;"(if int is type defined as atomic_t) rather atomic_t structure which only has one varaible:"int counter"?

Comment: According to the document I pointed, the reason they wrap the variable in a struct and define it as a type is to prevent any kind of cast to a normal C integer type.